# Determining dimension information and cropping using only an Image Byte Array

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3

I have an API set up to receive (amongst other things) an image byte array from a mobile app. Once received, the image is streamed to Amazon S3 and saved as a png. All good, however I have an issue where some images that are received are different dimensions.

Is it possible to determine the width and height of the image using only the byte array (ie, not saving it as an image to the server first), and if necessary crop the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out in the end, and it goes something like this:

```
// First get the data and decode    
$image_data = base64_decode($image_data);
$image_created = imagecreatefromstring($image_data);
$image_width = imagesx($image_created);
$image_height = imagesy($image_created);
$image_aspect_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
$desired_aspect_ratio = 512 / 512;

// Check if we need to resize
if($image_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio) {
    $manipulate_image = true;
    $temp_height = 512;
    $temp_width = ( int ) (512 * $image_aspect_ratio);
} else if($image_aspect_ratio < $desired_aspect_ratio) {
    $manipulate_image = true;
    $temp_width = 512;
    $temp_height = ( int ) (512 / $image_aspect_ratio);
} else {
    $manipulate_image = false;
}

// Resize if neccesary
if($manipulate_image){
    $temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($temp_width, $temp_height);
    $x0 = ($temp_width - 512) / 2;
    $y0 = ($temp_height - 512) / 2;
    imagecopyresampled($temp_gdim, $image_created, 0, 0, 0, 0, $temp_width, $temp_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor(512, 512);
    imagecopy($desired_gdim, $temp_gdim, 0, 0, $x0, $y0, 512, 512);

    // Now get the string back
    ob_start();
    imagepng($desired_gdim);
    $image_data =  ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    imagedestroy($image_created);
    imagedestroy($desired_gdim);            
}
```

The general gist of it I found here:
http://salman-w.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/crop-to-fit-image-using-aspphp.html